# Are angle brackets allowed in html 5 data attribute? If so how to find it with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I wondered whether it is allowed to store angle brackets inside a html 5 data attribute. In my example I need to store email addresses inside this attribute. This looks like:

```
<input class="email" data-email="Name <a@z.com>">
<input class="email" data-email="Name <b@z.com>">
```

There was no problem in the browser until I tried to find the element with a certain email address with jQuery.

```
$('.email[data-email="Name <a@z.com>"]')
```

This didn't work. So I asked myself whether it is allowed and if so how to select it with jQuery. If not - is there another way how to solve this problem?

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zk21k3gd/

Comment: Indeed your fiddle with jQuery 1.9.1 works fine! I tested it again on my local machine and it didn't work. So I checked my jQuery version and it's 1.7.1. And look at the [same fiddle like yours but with jQuery 1.7.2](http://jsfiddle.net/zk21k3gd/1/) - it doesn't work. So I have to update my jQuery version.

Comment: Yes, the simplest is to use recent jQuery version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
$('.email[data-email*="a@z.com"]')
```

Here `*` is a wildcard saying that select element whose atttibute contains `a@z.com`

Comment: My question was wrong. So I edited it after this answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is wrong with jQuery, but pure JS seems to be working:

```
document.querySelector('.email[data-email="Name <a@z.com>"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not matching the full value of the field, you can't use the `=` operator; `*=` is substring comparison:

```js
$('.email[data-email*="<a@z.com>"]').val("This one is a@z.com");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="email" data-email="Name <a@z.com>">
<input class="email" data-email="Name <b@z.com>">
```

Comment: My mistake... Of course I need a full match. So I've edited my question. Sorry!